# Excel VBA/Formula to find a cell that includes search term?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I was not sure how to really create the question...
But the problem I am having is this: I have a list (in rows) that relate to a regulatory document, and after trying to create some sort of for loop or elaborate VLookUp/Index formula, I'm requesting help.
For example:

[image: Excel Rows]

Now I want to use the rows to find the corresponding section in the document. I've already extracted and formatted the compliance document so it is in excel format.

So what I really need is this: a formula or VBA script that can
1. take the compliance number (for example 1A-1 which exist in Cell A3) and go find a cell (in single column D) that has JUST 1A-1, not 1A-1.1, not 1A-1.1.2, etc. and return it to the adjacent cell to 1A-1, for example.

Many thanks ahead of time... I am so lost!! :/

Comment: Why does this need to be an "elaborate" VLOOKUP?  This is literally what VLOOKUP *does*.  I.e. if your example above is A1:A7, `=VLOOKUP("1A-1", A1:A7, 1)`

Comment: I can understand you want to compare Cell A3 to Column D, but can you clarify further what you mean by "return to the adjacent cell to 1A-1? What value are you returning?

Comment: @comintern well the thing is I've tried using Vlookup for some time... as I have the compliance document seperated by the number and the next column over has the actual compliance information... 

So this is what it looks like at the moment: =VLOOKUP(A35,C:D,2,FALSE) and I get #N/A

Comment: @Basher I meant the adjacent cell as in if "1A-1" lived in A2, B2 would be the adjacent cell where I've run either VLookUp or some macro to extract information from the compliance doc info... which lives in C and D.

Does that clear up what I'm asking..?

Comment: @d.Kim Yes, and your code seems to be working fine when I test it out, assuming that the value in A35 exists in the C column.

Comment: @Basher see that is the problem I am having as well... The compliance number DOES show... it just doesn't want to be recognized for some reason, I have no idea what is going on..
I'm guessing I've been just running around in circles when the problem has been at the basic data level, not my logics...

Comment: @d.Kim If it's not the formula, it's your data. It's possible that you have a space after the data. Try selecting the C column, do CTRL+F and go to the Replace tab. Put a space on "Find What" and click "Replace all" and see if that works.

Comment: @Basher I've tried to find the cells and they show... so I'm not sure what is going on... I also tried your method for one of the cells, it did replace 4 cells but the vlookup still did not work. Truly mysterious and rather annoying...

Comment: Is the typo A35 in '=VLOOKUP(A35,C:D,2,FALSE)' your problem? It should be '=VLOOKUP(A3,C:D,2,FALSE)'. BTW from VBA Help: "If range_lookup is TRUE, the values in the first column of table_array must be placed in ascending order: ..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ..., A-Z, FALSE, TRUE; otherwise VLOOKUP may not give the correct value. If range_lookup is FALSE, table_array does NOT need to be sorted." In short: The data doesn't have be sorted. So it seems you're doing everything right. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

## VLOOKUP vs INDEX/MATCH

[image]

You can do the 'lookup' two ways (that I'm aware of):

Using **VLOOKUP**:

The B3 cell contains your formula

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,C:D,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(A3,C:D,2,FALSE))
```

where '**FALSE**' is indicating there has to be an exact match and the data doesn't have to be sorted.

Using **INDEX** with **MATCH**:

The F3 cell contains the Index/Match formula

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A3,C:C,0)),"",INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A3,C:C,0)))
```

where '**0**' is indicating there has to be an exact match and the data doesn't have to be sorted.

### INDEX/MATCH preferable!?

The **MATCH** function finds the position (row number if whole column is used) of the f**ound match**. This way (there's another) of using the **INDEX** function uses exactly this **found match** to return a cell's value in that position (row) in **ANY** specified column range (column). So they are the ideal combination.

With the **VLOOKUP** function you have to additionally specify the column index (range_lookup) of a range which could get complicated when the columns aren't adjacent as in this case. Most importantly, the function doesn't work if the lookup data is to the right of the match data.

[[image]VLOOKUP NOT WORKING! INDEX/MATCH STILL WORKING!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL6ws.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

try this formula

[image]

The formula in cells

```
B2: =INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A2,F:F,0))
C2: =INDEX(G:G,MATCH(A2,F:F,0))
```

- MATCH(A2,F:F,0) is finding Cell A2 in column F (0 means it will find
  exact match) and will return the first row number when it would find that
- INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A2,F:F,0)) will return contents of column E where row number is returned by the Match formula